# Value doesn't assign to struct(Pointers)

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

When I try assign value to `*temp`, it doesn't assign the value (when I'm compiling, it doesn't show the printf and by printf can't see any value assigned). Why ? How can I handle more about pointer (see where they're referencing with outer application from my IDE...?)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #define INT_SIZE sizeof(int) * 8
    
    typedef struct Node Node;
    struct Node
    {
        int value;
        Node *next;
    };
    
    
    typedef struct LinkedList
    {
        Node *head;
    }LinkedList;
    
    
    void Insert(LinkedList **lst, int data)
    {
        Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(Node)); 
        //Check's if is the first Node.
        if ((*lst)->head->next== NULL)
        {       
            (*lst)->head->next = temp;  
            temp->value = data;
            printf("Ok");   
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
    }
```

And my main function:

```
int main()
{
    LinkedList *list = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList)); //Create new linkedlist
    list->head->next = NULL; //Define the head object
    Insert(&list, 20);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you call ```Insert```?

Comment: How do you plan to end up with a valid, allocated, initialized item at position `(*lst)->head`? If you don't then, that's your problem.

Comment: in your main `list->head` is not initialized, you cannot access to `list->head->next`

Comment: @Jose  I've edited the post and added the main function.

Comment: Ok so after edit: `list->head` isn't pointing anywhere so you can't access `lists->head->next`...

Comment: @Lundin I've edited the post and added the main function(where I initialized head).

Comment: @Sababoni again no,  `list->head` is not initialized, you dereference a non initialized address. When you create your list it is empty => `list->head = NULL;`

Comment: @bruno then I should've added to my main function : list->head = malloc(sizeof(Node)); ?

Comment: @Sababoni and also *Insert* is wront because it has to manage the empty list, and it has to insert the element in **all** cases

Comment: There are thousands of working linked list implementations in C out there. Have you looked at one of them to find out?

Comment: `list->head = malloc(sizeof(Node));` no, an empty list is empty => no node

Comment: What's going to happen with the allocated memory if `((*lst)->head->next== NULL)` is false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of errors in your code

In main :

> ```
> LinkedList *list = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList)); //Create new linkedlist
> list->head->next = NULL; //Define the head object
> ```

is wrong because `list->head`is not initialized, so to set `list->head->next` has an undefined behavior

There is also a problem of logic, an empty list is empty => no node, the right initialization is :

```
list->head = NULL;
```

In Insert :

> ```
> if ((*lst)->head->next== NULL)
> ```

again this is invalid in case the list is empty because `(*lst)->head` is NULL (after the correction above).

Also there is no *else* branch, the function must always insert the new node.

To implement in the right way it is needed to know where the insert must be done, is your list a fifo, a lifo, or nodes are sorted depending on the value ?

Supposing a node is always inserted on the head :

```
void Insert(LinkedList **lst, int data)
{
    Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp)); 

    temp->value = data;
    temp->next = (*lst)->head;
    (*lst)->head = temp;
}
```

Note it is useless to use your double pointer, you can have :

```
void Insert(LinkedList *lst, int data)
{
    Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp)); 

    temp->value = data;
    temp->next = lst->head;
    lst->head = temp;
}

int main()
{
    LinkedList *list = malloc(sizeof(*list)); //Create new linkedlist
    list->head = NULL;
    Insert(list, 20);
    return 0;
}
```

Finally :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
  int value;
  struct Node *next;
} Node;
    
    
typedef struct LinkedList {
  Node *head;
} LinkedList;

void Insert(LinkedList *lst, int data)
{
    Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp)); 

    temp->value = data;
    temp->next = lst->head;
    lst->head = temp;
}

void pr(const LinkedList *lst)
{
  const Node * l = lst->head;
  
  while (l != NULL) {
    printf("%d ", l->value);
    l = l->next;
  }
  putchar('\n');
}

int main()
{
    LinkedList *list = malloc(sizeof(*list)); //Create new linkedlist
    list->head = NULL;
    Insert(list, 20);
    pr(list);
    Insert(list, 10);
    pr(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % gcc -Wall l.c
/tmp % ./a.out
20 
10 20 
/tmp %
```

Comment: Thanks !I've edited my code a little by your emphasis and it worked ! I can share my code.

Comment: you welcome, of course if you want to insert a new node at the end rather than the head you have to modify *Insert*

Comment: Why do you advice against double pointers? They are the way to go for linked lists as they make the implementation much cleaner.

Comment: @klutt for the current case they are useless, I never said this is the case in general ... or may be my answer is not enough clear ?

Comment: @bruno Yes, you are right. I read the answer to fast.

Comment: @klutt not a problem

Answer (score 1):

You allocated a list dynamically

```
LinkedList *list = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
```

but its data member `head` was not initialized. As a result the next statement

```
list->head->next = NULL;
```

invokes undefined behavior because there is used the variable `head` with an indeterminate value.

There is no sense to declare the first parameter of the function `Insert` as having the type `LinkedList **lst` that is to use two indirections to access the original list. It is much better to declare the function like

```
int Insert( LinkedList *list, int data );
```

To check whether the list is empty you had to write at least like

```
    if ( ( *lst )->head == NULL )
```

Moreover if the list is not empty your function does nothing.

Pay attention to that in general you should check whether an allocation of a new node was successful.

The function can be defined the following way

```
int Insert( LinkedList *list, int data )
{
    Node *temp = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    int success = temp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {       
        temp->value = data;
        temp->next  = list->head;
        list->head = temp;
    }

    return success;
}
```

There is no any need to allocate the list itself dynamically. You could just write

```
LinkedList list = { .head = NULL };

Insert( &list, 20 );
```

Pay attention to that you need to write a function that frees all allocated memory. For example

```
void Delete( LinkedList *list )
{
    while ( list->head != NULL )
    {
        Node *temp = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->next;
        free( temp );
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node *next;
};
    
    
typedef struct LinkedList
{
    Node *head;
} LinkedList;

int Insert( LinkedList *list, int data )
{
    Node *temp = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    int success = temp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {       
        temp->value = data;
        temp->next  = list->head;
        list->head = temp;
    }

    return success;
}

void Delete( LinkedList *list )
{
    while ( list->head != NULL )
    {
        Node *temp = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->next;
        free( temp );
    }
}

void Display( const LinkedList *list )
{
    for ( const Node *current = list->head; current != NULL; current = current->next ) 
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", current->value );
    }
    
    puts( "null" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    LinkedList list = { .head = NULL };
    
    const int N = 10;
    
    for ( int i = N; i != 0; i-- )
    {
        Insert( &list, i );
    }
    
    Display( &list );
    
    Delete( &list );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> null
```

If your compiler does not support the designating initialization then instead of this declaration

```
    LinkedList list = { .head = NULL };
```

you may just write

```
    LinkedList list = { NULL };
```

If you want to append new nodes to the tail of the list when the function `Insert` can look the following way

```
int Insert( LinkedList *list, int data )
{
    Node *temp = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    int success = temp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {       
        temp->value = data;
        temp->next  = NULL;
        
        Node **current = &list->head;
        while ( *current ) current = &( *current )->next;
        
        *current = temp;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use memory without allocating it. `LinkedList *` points to a valid (dynamically allocated) structure, but `head` points to nowhere (no reserved space for `Node`), so as soon as you try to write it, seg fault.

You have two options:

- Reserve space with `malloc` for `head` as you did with `LinkedList`
- Not declare `head` as a pointer and allocate its space in
  stack/global (`Node head`).

Same for `Node *next;`, consider if you want the pointer to point to an already valid `Node` in the rest of your code.

Another problem is that you are not releasing the dynamic memory, not sure if your code is just an example or you do have a memory leak.

Comment: It would be nice to get an explanation for the down voting

Answer (score -2):

You have not allocated memory for `list->head`, meaning you cannot access or modify `list->head->next`.

You should first allocate memory for the the head of the list :

```
int main()
{
    LinkedList *list = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList)); //Create new linkedlist
    list->head = malloc(sizeof(Node)); //Create head
    list->head->next = NULL; //Define the head object
    Insert(&list, 20);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Technically, it will work, but it's not a good solution